# What does "d.addCallback(lambda protocol: protocol.ready)" do in Pika's Twisted example?

Tags: python, twisted, pika, twisted.internet, python-pika

The setup in [Pika's example code with Twisted](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/dc628a65cbc339f6406e2908fd31e44163cca796/docs/examples/twisted_example.rst) looks like this:

```
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters()
cc = protocol.ClientCreator(
        reactor, twisted_connection.TwistedProtocolConnection, parameters)
d = cc.connectTCP('hostname', 5672)
d.addCallback(lambda protocol: protocol.ready)
d.addCallback(run)
reactor.run()
```

What effect does the `d.addCallback(lambda protocol: protocol.ready)` line have? Is reading the `.ready` attribute side-effecting? Or does `addCallback` use the return value of the callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return value of each callback is passed to next callback in the `d`'s callback chain.  So, `protocol.ready` value is passed to `run` (next callback).

See http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html#multiple-callbacks

Comment: Chris, http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html#multiple-callbacks